# TIBCO Design consideration

Tags: tibco

I am planning to implement Tibco based EAI. I would like to know how are the following components used in a typical EAI scenario.

1- TIBCo BW

2- TIBCo EMS

3- TIBCo BW admin.

4- TIBCo HAWK

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer : All of them.

Complex answer :

All of them are typically used by every TIBCO client I met, but they are all optional. ;-)

BW is the main reason people typically want to talk to TIBCO. It's one of the best  solid/easy/reliable/RAD integration server. Comparable to IBM IIB or Software AG webMethods Integration Server. FOSS similar offerings are Talend, Mule or Apache Camel...

EMS is the typical BW back bone. Chances are that if you are into integration, you are also interested in messaging. Messaging allow clear separation between client and server, persistence, load sharing, asynchronous processes, tolerance to failure on client or server side, pub/sub and much more. [EMS is VERY easy to install, under stand and manage](http://www.integist.info/2014/07/11/tibco-ems-on-centos-vm/). Think of it as a simple IBM MQ, or more corporate Active MQ. If you have layers in the BW architecture, chances are you will use EMS for inner layer communication. So much to say on EMS.

Administrator is useful and/or almost mandatory to administrate BW. More than a deployment platform (deployment can be done with scripts as well), the administrator allow you to change BW process properties and restart BW processes. There is also a section for basic EMS administration.

Hawk is a monitoring engine, tightly tied to BW, EMS (than can be used as Hawk's transport) and administrator. The product is facultative if you already have an OS/Servers monitoring solution... But is one of the easiest way to apply APPLICATIVE monitoring to all the product above (ex: give the state of a process in BW).

Note : Don't forget the DB requirement for the Administrator.
Note 2 : My answer is focused on TIBCO BW5... TIBCO BW6 engine and administrator are different... but my answer would be similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, But I am still wondering where exactly the combination of EMS and BW will be used. Is it only for reliable/guaranteed/persistent  messaging ? Can i implement scalable architecture if i use only TIBCO BW ?

Comment: Well, yes. In certain cases. As an example : If your architecture is not divided in layers (layering with BW is often implemented with EMS),AND is primarily something simple like exposition of web services with data transformation and a (scaled) database back-end... Then you can load balance multiple instances of BW with a simple load balancer unit, and create a scalable architecture without EMS.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with GhislainCote till some extent but to be frank, you need professional consulting to implement a solution with Tibco stack.

- Tibco EMS - backbone of Enterprise software
- Tibco BW - where you will do some business logic
- Tibco Admin - Used for governance, manage and deploy the services.
- Tibco HAWK - it is used for Monitoring serices and Infra

Answer (score 0):

1- TIBCo BW : where you have to develop your processes ( logic and alg)

2- TIBCo EMS : Entreprise Messaging system : a software to exchange messages via queues or topics

3- TIBCo BW admin : a tool for administration : deploying apps, manage space, show apps status ....

4- TIBCo HAWK : we can call it the tibco engine

if you want more you can check the Tibco official docs